# Xamarin iOS AppNexus Binding - `type could not be found`

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I have created my binding and resolved all issues with my `ApiDefinition` and `Structs` classes.

However when I compile the project, the generated `.g` files all complain about any types outside the class can not be found.

I have created a test project to replicate the issue. The errors appear when building the project.

https://github.com/c-lamont/AppNexus.Xamarin.iOS/tree/master/AppNexus.Xamarin.iOS/AppNexus.Xamarin.iOS

**Error Message**

`Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'xxxxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (AppNexus.Xamarin.iOS)`

Comment: please post an example of the specific error messages your are receiving, and the relevant code that generates them.  Do not expect us to download your code and debug it for you.

Comment: Added requested error message and how to generate the errors.

Comment: which specific namespace(s) is it complaining about?

Comment: Mostly missing `IANAdProtocol`. Also `IANCustomAdapterInterstitial`, `IANInterstitialAdDelegate` and `IANBannerAdViewDelegate`

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj ,then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: That does not resolve the issue.